# CSS Sprite not working

Tags: css, css-sprites

I'm trying to set up a sprite menu but it's always showing first slide of srpite, in all links. This is my CSS:

```
#menu-social{float: right; width: 175px; margin-top: 5px; list-style-type: none;}
#menu-social li{display: inline-block; margin-right: 8px;}
#menu-social li a{display: block; height: 18px; background: url(images/spr_sociales.png) transparent no-repeat;}

#link-google-plus{width: 30px; background-position: 0 0;}
#link-twitter{width: 21px; background-position-x: -30px; /*or background-position:  0 -30px;*/}
#link-facebook{width: 21px; background-position:  0 -51px;}
#link-tuenti{width: 21px; background-position:  0 -72px;}
```

But it always shows Google+ icon, which is the first one in the sprite.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your sprite image somewhere? And also html code relevant to that section?

Comment: seems like you use too much ids here. ids tend to have higher "specificity". where's your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having what I call a **selector score** issue.. Since your first rule `#menu-social li a` uses an **ID + element + element**, it overload the following rules `#link-facebook`, with only the ID.

> In other words:
>
> - For each ID value, apply 100 points
> - For each class value (or pseudo-class or attribute selector), apply 10 points
> - For each element reference, apply 1 point

Give a try on this snippet:

```
#menu-social { float: right; width: 175px; margin-top: 5px; list-style-type: none;}
#menu-social li { display: inline-block; margin-right: 8px;}
#menu-social li a { display: block; height: 18px; background: url(images/spr_sociales.png) transparent no-repeat;}

#menu-social li a#link-google-plus { width: 30px; background-position: 0 0; }
#menu-social li a#link-twitter { width: 21px; background-position-x: -30px; /*or background-position:  0 -30px;*/ }
#menu-social li a#link-facebook { width: 21px; background-position:  0 -51px; }
#menu-social li a#link-tuent { width: 21px; background-position:  0 -72px; }
```

A simple/elegant solution would be to change the IDs to classes (you don't need that much IDs), like this:

```
#menu-social li a { display: block; height: 18px; background: url(images/spr_sociales.png) transparent no-repeat;}

#menu-social li a.link-google-plus { width: 30px; background-position: 0 0; }
#menu-social li a.link-twitter { width: 21px; background-position-x: -30px; /*or background-position:  0 -30px;*/ }
#menu-social li a.link-facebook { width: 21px; background-position:  0 -51px; }
#menu-social li a.link-tuent { width: 21px; background-position:  0 -72px; }
```

More links on this issue here:

1. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
2. http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
3. http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Try that.

Comment: I think it's referred to as *selector specificity*.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read those links, never heard of "specifity" before