# CSS Sprite Not Working - Displays Only First Image in Set

Tags: css, css-sprites, sprite

Yes, I have been here: [CSS Sprite not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224010/css-sprite-not-working)

No, I don't get it. What does he mean by 'points'?:

"In other words:

For each ID value, apply 100 points
For each class value (or pseudo-class or attribute selector), apply 10 points
For each element reference, apply 1 point"

What are these 'points'? I read the articles and I get that there is order in specifying CSS codes, but I still don't understand. Right as this is I am only getting the very first sprite in the set. FYI-I used a sprite generator. ([This one to be exact](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/))

You can view the source code [here](http://nos.heliohost.org/pc/). I would suggest zooming in on your browser to see everything properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky: The img tag is occluding the background. I recommend changing it to a div. Also, you didn't include the NOS object in your code. Here's what I came up with:

```
<script>
    var NOS = {
        itemno: 0,
        menuClasses: [
            'img-blog',
            'img-files',
            'img-forums',
            'img-login',
            'img-logout',
            'img-mail',
            'img-news',
            'img-profile',
            'img-reg',
            'img-settings',
            'img-shop',
            'img-status'
        ],
        toggle: function() {
            $('#menuimg').removeAttr('class').addClass(function() {
                ++NOS.itemno;
                if (NOS.itemno > NOS.menuClasses.length - 1) {
                    NOS.itemno = 0;
                }
                return NOS.menuClasses[NOS.itemno]; 
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: For NOS, I just didn't bother to copy my JS into my question, but thanks anyways! I'll try the div then!